# Executar trigger de acordo com o valor de uma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso que essa trigger seja executada quando houver um update na tabela `auction`, porém somente quando o valor da coluna `auc_status` for igual a **3**.

Ou seja, assim que o valor de `auc_status` for alterado para **3**, ele deve executar a trigger.

Tentei fazer dessa forma:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_bid
    AFTER UPDATE ON auction
    FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
IF (NEW.auc_status = '3') THEN
    /* Conteúdo da trigger, que seriam dois updates em outra tabela */
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Esta correto ou devo fazer de outra forma? Utilizo o MySQL.

Comment: não está funcionado? ou você perguntou se tem outra forma de fazer?

Comment: Funciona, apenas quero saber se é a forma correta de fazer para não ter problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que ficaria melhor

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_bid
    AFTER UPDATE ON auction
    FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
IF ((OLD.auc_status <> NEW.auc_status) and (NEW.auc_status = '3')) THEN
    /* Conteúdo da trigger, que seriam dois updates em outra tabela */
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Perfeito, qual a diferença de usar o `<>` e `<=>`?

Comment: Não sei , supos o "diferente" ser  <>